# Looping through a list in razor and adding a separator between items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list of items which I want to output in a razor view. Between each item I want to add a separator line, like this:

```
item1 | item2 | item3
```

The simplest way to loop through items is with a foreach:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.items){
  <span>@item.Name</span> | 
}
```

Unfortunately this adds an extra separator line at the end of the list. Is there a simple way to skip this last separator line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `string.Join`:

```
@Html.Raw(string.Join("|", model.Items.Select(s => string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", s.Name))))
```

Using `string.Join` negates the need to check for the last item.

You can mix this with a Razor `@helper` method for more complex markup:

```
@helper ComplexMarkup(ItemType item)
{ 
    <span>@item.Name</span>
}

@Html.Raw(string.Join("|", model.Items.Select(s => ComplexMarkup(s))))
```

You could even create a helper method to abstract the `Html.Raw()` and `string.Join()` calls:

```
public static HtmlString LoopWithSeparator
    (this HtmlHelper helper, string separator, IEnumerable<object> items)
{
    return new HtmlString
          (helper.Raw(string.Join(separator, items)).ToHtmlString());
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.LoopWithSeparator("|",  model.Items.Select(s => ComplexMarkup(s)))
```

Comment: This seems suitable only for very simple loop bodies.

Comment: This seems almost perfect, the only problem is the way it flows; defining the inside of the loop first, then the separator, then the loop. It is by far the best one though

Comment: This does not produce HTML, it only produces text

Comment: Sorry, I have added the Html.Raw method

Answer (score 5):

Combining the other answers here with [this article on inline templates](https://web.archive.org/web/20130331224320/http://blogg.sigma.se/en/Development/Mario-Ienasescu/Dates/2012/12/Inline-templates-in-Razor/), I came up with this helper method, which can be put in an extension class:

```cs
public static HelperResult Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, HelperResult> template, Func<T, HelperResult> separator)
{
    var first = true;
    var result = new HelperResult(writer =>
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (first == false)
                separator(item).WriteTo(writer);
            first = false;
            template(item).WriteTo(writer);
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

The way to use it would then be

```html
@Model.ListOfItems.Join(
    @<a href="@item.Href">
        @item.Name
    </a>, 
    @<text> | </text>)
```

This supports html in both the items and the separator.

Comment: Phil Haack did something similar, so you're in good company :).

Comment: Nice, great use case for [**Templated Razor delegates**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0#templated-razor-delegates)!

Answer (score 3):

Keep a counter variable and inside the loop and check whether it is the last item or not.

```
@{ int counter=0; }
@foreach(var item in Model.items){
  counter++;
  <span>@item.Name</span>
  if(counter<Model.Items.Count) 
  {
    @Html.Raw("|")
  } 
}
```

and the short version is

```
@{ int counter=0; }
@foreach(var item in Model.items){
  counter++;
  <span>@item.Name</span> @(counter< Model.items.Count?"|":"")
 }
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it because I've never found a way to get something like this to work:

    @for(int i = 0; Model.items.Count; i++) 

Would love to know how it's done.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the simplest way, or if these is a more elegant way, but you could do something like;

```
@foreach ( var item in Model.items){
    <span>@item.Name</span> @(Model.items[Model.items.Count - 1] != item ? "|" : "")
}
```

So you are basically checking to see if the `item` is the last item in the list.

Not tried this code sample, so you might need to tweek it.